# How to Implement cooperative co-evolutionary GA Model on the Watchmaker Framework

Tags: java, genetic-algorithm, watchmaker

I am trying to implement a cooperative co-evolutionary GA based model where I have two populations with different data type and they should interact with each other to produce a better result after each generation. I am using the Watchmaker framework to do this. I have built the first population and I am trying now to add the second population. I am not sure how to do this. I could not find any class or method that support adding a second population. All what I have found is the Package org.uncommons.watchmaker.framework.islands class that Manages parallel evolution across multiple EvolutionEngines (islands) with periodic migration between them. I am not sure if this could help me, but from what I have understood that this class support populations with similar data types.

Can any one help me with this issue? Is there any way to implement a coevolutionary GA Model using the watchmaker framework? I have done a huge work and I don't want to change the framework if there is any possible way to do it in this framework.

Comment: In what way do you want the populations to "interact with each other to produce a better result"? There probably isn't exactly what you are looking for within the framework at present but it may be possible to use the existing classes as building blocks to implement what you need. Off the top of my head, you may be able to sub-class one of the existing evolution engines and override the `nextEvolutionStep` method to manipulate the population.

Comment: each one of the populations will use the data on the other population to produce a better population result. I will check the nextEvolutionStep method and I will see if it may work. If it didn't, do you suggest any other tool that might be powerful enough to implement a cooperative coevolution model?

Comment: Is there any implemented example that uses the nextEvolutionStep() method? I would like to know where exactly should I call this method and how to make the first population that calls the method interact with the second population?